# How to derive a formula for the first n powers of an integer?

Tags: exponentiation

How to derive a formula for the first n powers of an integer? In particular, sum of 2^n? I'm looking for a proof that not only utilizes algebraic manipulation but is also easily seen visually.

Comment: Probably you mean the sum of a geometric progression: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression

Comment: Yes, I think this is a specific type of geometric progression. However, I'm looking for a proof that not only utilizes algebraic manipulation but is also easily seen visually.

Answer (score 3):

OK, here's a picture.

[image]

The green rectangles have heights $1, r, r^2, \ldots r^n$ where in this case $n=7$.
Each blue rectangle on the left has $r-1$ times the height of the green rectangle below it, so the green and blue together have height $r$ times the green alone.  The sum of the
lengths of the blue rectangles on the left is thus $r-1$ times the sum of the lengths of the corresponding green rectangles, i.e. $(r-1)(1 + r + \ldots + r^n)$.  But on the right we 
see that the sum of the lengths of the blue rectangles is $r^{n+1} - 1$.  So
$(r-1)(1 + r + \ldots + r^n) = r^{n+1}-1$, or $$1 + r + \ldots + r^n = \frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}$$

Comment: Perhaps the widths of the rectangles should be $1/(r-1)$, so the sum of the areas of the glue rectangles is $1+r+\ldots r^n$.

Comment: I appreciate this. Could you read it over and insert nouns and otherwise edit it for clarity? E.g., is "height" between "has" and "r−1"? "Each blue rectangle on the left has r−1 times the height of the green rectangle below it, so the green and blue together have height r times the green alone." I couldn't understand why this is so until I wrote (r−1)g+g=gr-g+g=gr. How is that evident from the picture? If the length of r was marked perhaps it'd be easier to see.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want a formula for $x + x^2 + \ldots x^n$?  Look up "geometric series".

Answer (score 0):

We'll show that
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} 2^i= 2^{n+1} - 2.$$
Denote this sum by
$$ S(n) = 2^1 + 2^2 + \ldots  + 2^{n-1} + 2^n \tag{1}$$
On the RHS, factor out a $2$, we get
$$ S(n) = 2(1 + 2^1 + \ldots + 2^{n-1})$$
But from $(1),$ we have $ 2^1 + \ldots + 2^{n-1} = S(n) - 2^n.$ So
$$ S(n) = 2(1 + \underbrace{2^1 + \ldots + 2^{n-1}}_{S(n) - 2^n})\\
S(n) = 2(1+ S(n)-2^n)\\
S(n) = 2 + 2S(n) -2^{n+1} $$
Finally $$ S(n) = 2^{n+1} - 2.$$

Comment: I was looking rather for a way to easily see why the formula is true. Something like a picture proof or the proof that the sum of the numbers from 1 to n is n(n+1)/2 on http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/runsums/triNbProof.html. It should also easily generalize to other integers besides 2. Thank you for a proof anyway.

Comment: Another homework problem

Answer (score -1):

The geometric series for \frac{1}{2} is easily seen by dividing a $1\times1$ square. You can get the one u want by multiplying by $2^n$.

Comment: Could you elaborate or draw a picture?